# WD "My Passport Ultra" not recognizes in kubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Works fine on my wife's Mint 19.3 machine

```
[29439.367051] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[29439.367055] usb 2-3: Product: My Passport 259F
[29439.367057] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[29439.367060] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 575847314136364543394A45
[29439.378717] usb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[29439.379044] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[29440.420867] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 259F 1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29440.421162] scsi 3:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29440.423381] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[29440.423716] ses 3:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[29440.424076] ses 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 13
[29440.433722] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[29441.466219] .
[29472.072189] usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[29472.221039] ses 3:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[29472.221045] ses 3:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[29472.233248] not responding...
[29652.246770] sd 3:0:0:0: tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
```

Comment: Sorry there are problems. What can we do for you?

Comment: Help me solve the issue?  WD “My Passport Ultra” not recognized by kubuntu?

Comment: I don't know if this is related to Kubuntu at all. More often then not, it is a problem with the USB port itself.

Comment: well I take it you want help with a usb disk that is not mounting? the quoted bit shows it connects and is detected by the system the rest of your stuff seems to say it times out "sb-storage 2-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[29439.379044] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-3:1.0
[29440.420867] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 259F 1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29440.421162] scsi 3:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1015 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6"

Comment: How big is this USB drive? Does it have its own AC power adapter? USB2 or USB3 device?

Comment: it is a 1T drive.

Comment: Did you init this drive by first laying down a fresh GPT/MBR partition table... or did you just start using the drive out of the box? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: It uses usb power.  I reformatted it to fat 32, I think?